# Cant pass cmd argument to index.ts using yarn

Tags: javascript, npm, yarnpkg

My goal is to pass arguments throw cmd using yarn start to `index.ts`.

```json
"scripts": {
  "start": "tsc-watch --onSuccess \"ts-node --pretty -r tsconfig-paths/register' src/index.ts\"",
}
```

When I try something like:

```
yarn start --matchId 5eb8d34d9bdbf3735005fc3d
```

I got:

> ```
> $ tsc-watch --onSuccess "ts-node --pretty -r tsconfig-paths/register' src/index.ts" --matchId 5eb8d34d9bdbf3735005fc3d
> error TS5023: Unknown compiler option '--matchId'.
> ```

My question how to pass variables throw cmd to index.ts script?

Comment: Did you try

> yarn start -- --matchId 5eb8d34d9bdbf3735005fc3d

Answer (score 0):

When you want to pass an argument to the command as-is, you have to do like

> yarn command -- --arg value

So, you can try

> yarn start -- --matchId 5eb8d34d9bdbf3735005fc3d